# Draw the decision boundary of an neural network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, perceptron

[image]

I'm really confused when it comes to what the difference between bias and threshold is. I have read that they are basically the same thing and that they serve the same purpose. Being on opposite sides of the equation, though, they are "negatively proportional".

The equation for the separator for a single-layer perceptron is (Please correct me if I'm wrong.):

Σwjxj+bias=threshold

This means that if the input is higher than the threshold, or

Σwjxj+bias > threshold, it gets classified into one category, and if

Σwjxj+bias < threshold, it get classified into the other.

Starting with a).

For the first unit: 0 * x1 + 1 * x2 + 1 > 0 (0, because the threshold is 0) which is the same as x2+1 > 0.

For the second unit: x1 * 1 + x2 * 0 + 1 > 0 (0, because the threshold is 0) which is the same as x1 + 1 > 0.

For the third unit: x1 * 1 + x2 * 1 + 1 > -1 (-1, because the threshold is -1. I might have misunderstood this since the assignment states "Circles indicate threshold units with threshold at zero...") which is the same as x1 + x2 > -2.

I then draw those lines, but they don't correspond the the lines in the image below. What have I done wrong?

This is the given solution (but I don't understand how they got it):

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: Then yes, there is no difference between e.g. increasing the bias and decreasing the threshold. But, notice that it says the threshold is zero. So the threshold cannot be increase or decreased. Only the bias can be changed.